# Data corruption when replacing a GLSL constant with a uniform value

Tags: gpgpu, webgl2

Follow up to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55713667/data-corruption-when-replacing-uniform-array-with-1d-texture-in-webgl).

I am doing GPGPU programming in WebGL2, and I'm passing in a large 4-dimensional square array to my shaders by packing it into a texture to bypass the uniform count limits. Having freed myself from having to use a relatively small fixed-size array, I would like to be able to specify the size of the data that is actually being passed in programmatically.

Previously, I had hard-coded the size of the data to read using a `const int` as follows:

```
const int SIZE = 5;
const int SIZE2 = SIZE*SIZE;
const int SIZE3 = SIZE2*SIZE;

uniform sampler2D u_map;

int get_cell(vec4 m){
    ivec4 i = ivec4(mod(m,float(SIZE)));
    float r = texelFetch(u_map, ivec2(i.x*SIZE3+i.y*SIZE2+i.z*SIZE+i.w, 0), 0).r;
    return int(r * 255.0);
}
```

If I update `SIZE2` and `SIZE3` to be non-constant and initialized in main, it still works:

```
const int SIZE = 5;
int SIZE2;
int SIZE3;

uniform sampler2D u_map;

int get_cell(vec4 m){
    ivec4 i = ivec4(mod(m,float(SIZE)));
    float r = texelFetch(u_map, ivec2(i.x*SIZE3+i.y*SIZE2+i.z*SIZE+i.w, 0), 0).r;
    return int(r * 255.0);
}

...

void main(){
  SIZE2 = SIZE*SIZE;
  SIZE3 = SIZE*SIZE2;

  ...
}
```

However, if I then replace `const int SIZE = 5;` with `uniform int SIZE;`, and then add

```
const size_loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "SIZE");
gl.uniform1i(size_loc, 5);
```

to the JavaScript side to set it to the same integer value that used to be hardcoded, I start seeing incorrect values being read from the texture. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE 1: I did a little experiment where I keep the constant `SIZE` specification, but then also pass in a uniform int alongside it. If they are not equal, I have the shader bail out and return all zeroes. This way, I could verify that the correct integer values are in fact being set on the uniform variable--but if I then make `SIZE` non-constant, and set it to the value of the uniform variable *with which it was just compared and found to be equal* then things break. What the heck?

UPDATE 2:

This works:

```
int SIZE = 5;
uniform int u_size;
....
void main() {
  if (u_size != SIZE) return;
  SIZE = u_size;
  ...
}
```

This doesn't:

```
int SIZE = 5;
uniform int u_size;
....
void main() {
  SIZE = u_size;
  ...
}
```

Comment: You do call `gl.useProgram(program);` somewhere before `gl.uniform1i(size_loc, 5);`, don't you?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes. There are several pre-existing uniform variables that work, and have always worked, just fine.

Comment: It occured to me that all of my other uniform values, with the exception of texture locations, were floats. So, I attempted passing in a uniform float and then casting it to int to initialize `SIZE`--but that ended up having exactly the same (incorrect) results.

Comment: It is just a guess, but does the issue still occur if you do `ivec2(i.x*SIZE*SIZE*SIZE+i.y*SIZE*SIZE+i.z*SIZE+i.w, 0)`

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yup. :(

Comment: @Rabbid76 Well, it looks like I found an implementation bug in WebGL. I just tried it out multiple times with different data sizes on a different platform, and the bug disappeared!

Comment: Why is `m` a `vec4` not an `ivec4`? why are you using `mod` instead of `%`. Also `return` does not output nothing it outputs undefined. If you want to output nothing you need to call `discard`

Comment: @gman `m` is a `vec4` and not an `ivec4` because it needs to accumulate fractional components, and centralizing the conversion reduces messiness elsewhere in the code. `%` did not exist is GLSL ES 2.0 in which this code was originally written, and there was no need to replace the use of `mod` since it still works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your issue. Post a [minimal, complete, verifiable, example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349790/128511) in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Here's a working example

```js
const vs = `#version 300 es
void main() {
  gl_PointSize = 1.0;
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;
const fs = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform ivec4 cell;
uniform int SIZE;
int SIZE2;
int SIZE3;

uniform highp isampler2D u_map;

int get_cell(ivec4 m){
    ivec4 i = m % SIZE;
    int r = texelFetch(u_map, ivec2(i.x*SIZE3 + i.y*SIZE2 + i.z*SIZE + i.w, 0), 0).r;
    return r;
}

out int result;

void main(){
  SIZE2 = SIZE*SIZE;
  SIZE3 = SIZE*SIZE2;
  result = get_cell(cell);
}
`;


const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
// compile shaders, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// make a 1x1 R32I texture and attach to framebuffer
const framebufferInfo = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(gl, [
  { internalFormat: gl.R32I, minMag: gl.NEAREST, },
], 1, 1);

const size = 5;
const totalSize = size * size * size * size;
const data = new Int32Array(totalSize);
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  data[i] = 5 + i * 3;
}
// create a size*size*size*size by 1
// R32I texture
const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  width: totalSize,
  src: data,
  minMag: gl.NEAREST,
  internalFormat: gl.R32I,
});

gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebufferInfo.framebuffer);
gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);
gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

const result = new Int32Array(1);

for (let w = 0; w < size; ++w) {
  for (let z = 0; z < size; ++z) {
    for (let y = 0; y < size; ++y) {
      for (let x = 0; x < size; ++x) {
        // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
        twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
          cell: [x, y, z, w],
          u_map: tex,
          SIZE: size,
        });
        gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);  // draw 1 point
        gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RED_INTEGER, gl.INT, result);
        log(x, y, z, w, ':', result[0], data[x * size * size * size + y * size * size + z * size + w]);
      }
    }
  }
}

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
pre { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

trying with the code you posted I see no issues either

```js
const vs = `#version 300 es
void main() {
  gl_PointSize = 1.0;
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;
const fs = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform vec4 cell;
uniform int SIZE;
int SIZE2;
int SIZE3;

uniform sampler2D u_map;

int get_cell(vec4 m){
    ivec4 i = ivec4(mod(m,float(SIZE)));
    float r = texelFetch(u_map, ivec2(i.x*SIZE3+i.y*SIZE2+i.z*SIZE+i.w, 0), 0).r;
    return int(r * 255.0);
}

out float result;

void main(){
  SIZE2 = SIZE*SIZE;
  SIZE3 = SIZE*SIZE2;
  // output to texture is normalized float
  result = float(get_cell(cell)) / 255.0;
}
`;


const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
// compile shaders, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

const size = 5;
const totalSize = size * size * size * size;
const data = new Uint8Array(totalSize);
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  data[i] = (5 + i * 3) % 256;
}
// create a size*size*size*size by 1
// R8 texture
const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  width: totalSize,
  src: data,
  minMag: gl.NEAREST,
  internalFormat: gl.R8,
});

gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);
gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

const result = new Uint8Array(4);

for (let w = 0; w < size; ++w) {
  for (let z = 0; z < size; ++z) {
    for (let y = 0; y < size; ++y) {
      for (let x = 0; x < size; ++x) {
        // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
        twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
          cell: [x, y, z, w],
          u_map: tex,
          SIZE: size,
        });
        gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);  // draw 1 point
        gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, result);
        log(x, y, z, w, ':', result[0], data[x * size * size * size + y * size * size + z * size + w]);
      }
    }
  }
}

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
pre { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

Note that I wouldn't use a 1 dimensional texture since there is a limit on dimensions. I'd use a 3 dimensional texture to increase the limit

```js
const vs = `#version 300 es
void main() {
  gl_PointSize = 1.0;
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;
const fs = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform ivec4 cell;
uniform int SIZE;

uniform highp isampler3D u_map;

int get_cell(ivec4 m){
    // no idea why you made x major
    ivec4 i = m % SIZE;
    int r = texelFetch(
      u_map,
      ivec3(
          i.z * SIZE + i.w,
          i.yx),
      0).r;
    return r;
}

out int result;

void main(){
  result = get_cell(cell);
}
`;


const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
// compile shaders, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// make a 1x1 R32I texture and attach to framebuffer
const framebufferInfo = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(gl, [
  { internalFormat: gl.R32I, minMag: gl.NEAREST, },
], 1, 1);

const size = 5;
const totalSize = size * size * size * size;
const data = new Int32Array(totalSize);
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  data[i] = 5 + i * 3;
}
// create a size*size*size*size by 1
// R32I texture 3D
const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  target: gl.TEXTURE_3D,
  width: size * size,
  height: size,
  src: data,
  minMag: gl.NEAREST,
  internalFormat: gl.R32I,
});

gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebufferInfo.framebuffer);
gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);
gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

const result = new Int32Array(1);

for (let w = 0; w < size; ++w) {
  for (let z = 0; z < size; ++z) {
    for (let y = 0; y < size; ++y) {
      for (let x = 0; x < size; ++x) {
        // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
        twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
          cell: [x, y, z, w],
          u_map: tex,
          SIZE: size,
        });
        gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);  // draw 1 point
        gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RED_INTEGER, gl.INT, result);
        log(x, y, z, w, ':', result[0], data[x * size * size * size + y * size * size + z * size + w]);
      }
    }
  }
}

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
pre { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As I commented on the question, it appears to be a platform-specific bug. It's breaking in Chromium on MacOS, but not elsewhere so far. I would file a bug report, but the full application is large and it's not particularly worth it to me to put in the effort of paring it down to a minimal example since I can get it to work elsewhere. That's a good point about texture dimension limits, though; I'll have to look into that if I run into problems with the current approach. Thanks!

Comment: I'm on MacOS. Not seeing the bug. It's possible you found a bug. It's far more likely something is wrong with your code. There are platform specific issues precision issue so if you aren't calculating UVs correctly then you'll get issues. As one example converting from integer floats to actual integers can lead to unexpected results. This line `ivec4(mod(m,float(SIZE)));` is likely to be an issue. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388074/webgl-float-modulus-behaviour/47422761#47422761  There are other things as well. You need to post a repo if you want help.

Comment: Why would it make a difference to that line whether the same integer `SIZE` is specified as a constant or a uniform value?

Comment: One is computed at compile time with CPU precision. The other is executed at runtime with GPU precision. The point is without seeing your code we can't check if you're hitting a well known edge case.

Comment: Huh. I would've though 'precision' shouldn't matter for 32-bit integers...

Comment: Having slept on it, I think I understand you better. For the constant, the float conversion of `SIZE` can be computed at compile-time, rather than runtime. So I tried replacing that line `ivec4(m) % SIZE`... and I still see random wrong values in Chromium on Mac. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I'll see what happens if I constrain `m` to be an `ivec4` to start with.... EDIT: No change.

Comment: Try this `ivec4(mod(m + 0.5, float(SIZE)));` assuming `m` was supposed to be integer values to begin with. In any case it's not clear why you can't post an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349790/128511). I've given you a framework. It should be trivial for you to repo the issue with a small shader and simple data and then we can look at it and either point out issue or file a bug to be fixed.